# two QuerySets - merge/join on common foreign key of third model

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

I am now querying - independent of each other - the Models Price and Duration (scroll down for the model definition) through several filters. Finally, I want to merge Price and Duration Querysets so that one price is associated with the specific duration. Example:

Price - in QuerySet _prices:

```
id | provider | servicelevel | price | currency
1  | 1        | 1            | 10    | 1
2  | 1        | 1            | 20    | 2
3  | 2        | 2            | 15    | 1
```

Duration - in QuerySet _duration:

```
id | servicelevel | country_in | country_out | duration | duration_details
1  | 1            | 83         | 236         | 5        | 'only on working days'
2  | 2            | 83         | 236         | 3        | 'Mon-Thu'
```

**What I need to have: Price + Duration joined on Servicelevel**

```
id | provider | servicelevel | price | currency | duration | duration_details
1  | 1        | 1            | 10    | 1        | 5        | 'only on working days'
2  | 1        | 1            | 20    | 2        | 5        | 'only on working days'
3  | 2        | 2            | 15    | 1        | 3        | 'Mon-Thu'
```

I've played around with `annotate()`, `extra()`, but did not find a solution.

Models:

```
class Price(models.Model):
    ...
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    servicelevel = models.ForeignKey(Servicelevel)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.ForeignKey('api.Currency')
    ...

class Servicelevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    terms = models.TextField(blank=True)
    insurance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
class Duration(models.Model):
    servicelevel = models.ForeignKey(Servicelevel)
    country_out = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='duration_out_country_relation', null=True)
    country_in = models.ForeignKey('Country', related_name='duration_out_country_relation', null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    duration_details = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...
```

KH

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you select any service level, you can get to price or duration. Is this a display problem? For example if you have `p = Provider.objects.get(pk=1)`, then you can get `p.servicelevel_set.all()`, (all service levels for this provider) and then follow the relationship.

Comment: Hi Burhan, before I want to follow the relationship, I already queried Duration with an extensive filter statement to make sure that only one Duration for one Servicelevel is left over.

Comment: So you want to go from a duration to service level and then from there to provider?

Comment: I have two QuerySets: One of Price, and one of Duration. In the Price QuerySet, there are n prices with one Servicelevel each. In the Duration QuerySet, there are n rows with Servicelevel unique. I want to add the data of the Duration QuerySet to the Price QuerySet, so pseudo SQL would be "SELECT * FROM Price INNER JOIN Duration ON Price.Servicelevel = Duration.Servicelevel". But maybe my approach is the wrong direction?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Is it just for printing or something else?

Comment: Preferably also be able to further work with the result (would want to save the result in the DB), primary purpose would be printing though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two QuerySets: One of Price, and one of Duration. In the Price
>   QuerySet, there are n prices with one Servicelevel each. In the
>   Duration QuerySet, there are n rows with Servicelevel unique. I want
>   to add the data of the Duration QuerySet to the Price QuerySet

I think as this is for display purposes, you need to restructure your data:

```
results = {}

for p in price_queryset:
   results.setdefault(p.pk, []).append(p)
   for d in duration_queryset.filter(servicelevel=p.servicelevel):
       results[p.pk].append(d)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how I can access the data then? When I try result['price'], I get "'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: results is a dictionary. Key is the primary key of your price items, and the value is a list. First element of the list is the price item itself, followed by any duration items for the same service level as the price.

Answer (score 0):

If Duration and Servicelevel are one-to-one, then you could refactor your data model.  If they are not, do you want every permutation in the final report?

Check out the `_set` "backward" relationship manager:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Unfortunately, there is n Durations for one Servicelevel (each Servicelevel has different Durations depending on the country_in <-> country_out permutations). In my QuerySets selecting from Durations, I make sure that only one row for a Servicelevel appears.