# Concatenation foreign key in Django

Tags: python, join, foreign-keys, concatenation

I need a query to retrieve the name and id of the 4 model classes (P, B, M, C, Pt) with a concat.

The class Pt has the foreign key to the parents class by the id

The expected result should be like this: Pt.name, Product.num , concat(B.name, M.name, V.name)

I try several approaches and the more similar it's this one

**Models:**

```
class B(models.Model):
    b_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class M(models.Model):
    m_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class V(models.Model):
    v_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Pt(models.Model):
    pt_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Product(models.Model):
    p_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    p_ref_fk = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    pt_fk = models.ForeignKey(Pt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b_fk = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    m_fk = models.ForeignKey(M, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    v_fk = models.ForeignKey(V, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Query:**

```
# Get all the P related

    p = Product.objects.all().filter(pt_fk__pt_id=1116).filter(b_fk__b_id=3).filter(m_fk__m_id=53).filter(v_fk__v_id=352)

# check the query
print(p.query)

# get the results
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per i get your question, you need to Concat foreignkey with - Pt.name, Product.num , concat(B.name, M.name, V.name)

```
queryset = Employee.objects.annotate(fullname=Concat('first_name', 'last_name'))
```

this is my own example please change as per your requirements

[try this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321137/two-querysets-merge-join-on-common-foreign-key-of-third-model)

Comment: Yes it's what i need to do.
I'm new in Django and i'm trying to convert a project to Django.


Here it's a mysql query that do what i want:

similar query on mysql

`SELECT pt.name, product.price, CONCAT ('B:', b.name, ' M:', m.name, ' V:', v.name)

FROM product
INNER JOIN pt ON product.pt_fk = pt_id
INNER JOIN b ON product.b_fk = b_id
INNER JOIN m ON product.m_fk = m_id
INNER JOIN v ON product.v_fk = v_id

WHERE product.pt_fk = 2 
AND product.b_fk = 84
AND product.m_fk = 4818
AND product.v_fk = 51`